# Django i18n and SEO

Tags: django, seo, internationalization

how do you prepare i18n in your websites? I mean what do you do avoid the situation when you search for i18ned websites in Polish you get English description cause English is the default one.

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I give every language version it's own URL. So English version of an article would be avialiable under http://example.com/en/my-article, and a version in Polish under http://example.com/pl/my-article (or if you really care about SEO even under http://example.com/pl/moj-artykul).

Had I given all version the same URL (and switched content dynamically) Google would have indexed only one version, and users couldn't find the article using keywords from any other language. I also think having distinct URLs people can link to for every version is more user friendly.

Comment: I do this in both my personal and work projects. It guarantees that you know what language you'll be loading and displaying by default.

Comment: @LudwigTrammer, and how would you handle the root url (just slash). It's english by default for me, so google indexes my site's root in english because there's no language url yet